# instantiate view controller from fcm push notification

Tags: swift, storyboard, apple-push-notifications, appdelegate, uiscenedelegate

So for some reason, there is always an issue when instantiating from `AppDelegate`. I have a notification with a `UNNotificationAction` and I handle the action selection in the `didReceiveResponse()` method.

Here is the function:

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
    let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
  
       // Print message ID.
       if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
         print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
       }
    
   
    if response.actionIdentifier == "viewNewEvent" {
        let dashVC: UIViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: Constants.StoryboardIDs.StudentEventDashboardStoryboardID) as! StudentSegmentedTableViewController
        let navDashVC = UINavigationController(rootViewController: dashVC)
        self.window?.rootViewController = navDashVC
        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        
    }

       print(userInfo)
    print("didReceiveResponse called")

    completionHandler()
}
```

The block of code in the `if` statement never runs when I select the action in the notification.  At first, I was force unwrapping everything and I got an error saying the viewController was nil, now when I run and select the action in the notification, nothing happens.

How can the viewController be nil? I've faced something similar and decided to try it in the `SceneDelegate` instead, and it worked but there's so much bugs that I need to eventually fix.
Am I better off using a `UIScene` and `UIWindowScene` in this situation than just `UIWindow` to try to to instantiate the right VC? Or is there a solution to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so after a couple hours of research, I've realized that this cannot be done in `AppDelegate` anymore and I've now got to use SceneDelegate for anything to do with `UIWindow` and `UIScene.`